# Missing the point: Laravel 5 environment setup

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

So, for my application I see 4 types of environments it can run under:

1. Local on my machine
2. Local on my VM where I am using Homestead
3. Staging
4. Production

Each environment differs in the database connectivity (type of DB, connectivity to the DB credentials, etc).

In my bootstrap/start.php I have set up this:

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(
    'local' => array('localhost'),
    'localStaging' => array('mylocalStage.dev'),
    'staging' => array('myapp-stage.com'),
    'production' => array('myapp.com'),
));
```

How do I enforce those settings? where do I set up that when I'm on 'local' I will use some local settings? Currently when I use

`php artisan env`

on my root application folder I get:

`Current application environment: production`

why isn't it picking up I'm 'local'?

Comment: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/configuration#environment-configuration notice the ENV library usage part

Comment: http://laravel.io/forum/05-18-2014-how-to-set-the-current-environment

Comment: my generate laravel-5 project does not have any env.example or any .env file in its structure -- is that what I'm missing? where do I help it change from "production" to "local"? nothing i do changes that determination by "php artisan env"

Comment: In the root directory you should have an .env file (please notice that it has no name so you might need to do `ls -a` in order to see it). In this file you set the configs of the environment and use git.ignore in order to have a unique configs for each environment, and In your code you should use `$app->detectEnvironment()`,

Comment: did an ls -a -- there is no such file. Can I just generate it somehow?

Comment: You can copy its content from the `Git`: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/.env.example
Just name it `.env` (without the .example part)

Comment: did that. now I see local in response to __php artisan env__  thanks.

Comment: But now, what use could there be to the "detectEnvironment" if my .env file forces a local? is "detectEnvironment" even called now that I have a brute force .env file forcing local?

Comment: You need to have a different .env file for every environment. So in your local you have X settings in your .env file, in your production environment you'd have Y settings in your .env file. **Notice** that you should use `ignore` in order not to overwrite one of them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77543/discussion-between-rm1970-and-ofir-baruch).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After discussing the issue in the comments and in the chat, the conclusion was to use the new .ENV approach which have been introduced in laravel 5.

Which means, you should have an `.env` file in your root directory with the current environment's settings.

So for local env, your .env file would have different settings than your production's env .env file.

As default you should have a `.env.example` file, in case you don't have one - you can copy the default content from the git ([.env.example@git](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/.env.example)).

Please notice that when you're updating (pushing) your local version to staging (for instance), that you don't overwrite the `.env` file. In order to prevent those kind of issues you can use git ignore (so it will skip that file).